# Well definedness of C++ programs hiding pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, garbage-collection

[According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Allow_garbage_collected_implementations):

> C++11 defines conditions under which pointer values are "safely
>   derived" from other  values. An implementation may specify that it
>   operates under "strict pointer safety," in which case pointers that
>   are not derived according to these rules can become invalid.

As I read it you can get the safety model used by an implementation, however that's fixed for the compiler (possibly variable with a command line switch).

Suppose I have code that hides pointers, such code definitely would not run with a naive bolt on garbage collector. However collectors (like my own) and Boehm provide hooks for finding pointers in certain objects.

I am in particular thinking about JudyArrays. These are digital tries which necessarily hide the keys. My question is basically whether using such data structures would render the behaviour of a program undefined in C++11.

I hope not (since Judy Arrays outperform everything else). Also as it happens .. I'm using them to *implement* a garbage collector. I am concerned however because "minimal requirements" don't general work at all and were strongly opposed in the original debate on the C++ conformance model (by the UK and Australia). Parametric requirements are better. But the C++11 GC related text seems to be a bit of both so I'm confused!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's implementation defined whether an implementation provides relaxed pointer safety (what you seem to want) or strict pointer safety (pointers remain valid only when `safely derived`). As you've implied, you can call `get_pointer_safety` to find out what the policy is, but the standard provides no way to specify/change the policy.

You may, however, be able to side-step this question. If you can make a call to `declare_reachable` (passing that pointer value) before you hide the pointer, it remains valid until a matching call to `undeclare_reachable` (and here "matching" means calls nest).

Comment: In this case I could do it but it would probably be very expensive: the fastest way to keep track of that is undoubtedly to use a Judy Array, and that is precisely what the Judy Array I'm using is being used for. Assuming its not a nop, at best this would double access times, and (more likely) the C++ collector would be using an inferior data structure.

Comment: @Yttrill: Given that you're implementing a GC, perhaps it's reasonable to at least consider whether it shouldn't really be seen/act as part of the implementation. In this case, perhaps you'd be implementing `declare_reachable` as adding the pointer to your Judy Array.

Comment: My guess is that practical compilers will make the use of a system GC and the pointer safety policy controlled by the command line. Existing libgc implementations using Boehm collector can work with Judy I think, but you have to tell the collector about it. If you do so, however, you'd expect the program to work without declare_reachable, but technically the behaviour might be undefined.

Comment: well the GC is part of "the implementation" but I'm not implementing C++ but a language whose compiler generates C++. So I wouldn't be "implementing" declare_reachable, I'd have to think whether the generated code needed to call it or not.

Comment: @Yttrill: for a case like that, you'd have blocks of memory for your language's GC heap. You'd allocate those blocks with `new`, and retain pointers to them (at least semi-permanently) so the entire block would remain valid. Your GC would deal with smaller pieces inside there, but the whole block would remain valid regardless of hiding other pointers inside the block.

Comment: I could do that, but actually I don't: I call malloc directly rather than trying to suballocate. I figure the malloc implementors can do a better job than me.